# pm2 using nginx can not restart server when crash

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

I am deploying a server on aws ec2. I use pm2 and nginx. However, when the app is crash, the web app return 502 bad gate way. The server can not restart automatically. 
I reviewed other articles which suggest below code but it does not help.

`process.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
      console.log('An error has occured. error is: %s and stack trace is: %s', e, e.stack);
      console.log("Process will restart now.");
      process.exit(1);
    });`

Comment: By default `pm2` will restart your app.

Comment: How are you running pm2? is there any pm2 config file then please add it for more reference